# long-winded webpart question

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

I have a web part, in the `createchildcontrols` function it creates a `gridview`, calls a stored procedure and populates the grid view.  One column of the `gridView` is a command field that has the key value for an item & is passed to another web part on the page to show the details.  All was working fine until they wanted me to add a search capability to the list web part.

At first this appeared to work, the data in the columns sems to reflect correct search results, but the command field retains the orginal values when the page was first loaded with no search criteria.

Also, when doing the search it appears that it goes through the createchildcontrols function, populates gridview with all of the items, then runs through  the code in the `btnSearch_Click` where more sql is run with the specific search criteria and the gridview 
is re-bound with the search results (but orginal key values in command field).

Any ideas on how I've messed this up?

Code from `CreateChildControls`:

```
_view = new GridView();
this.Controls.Add(this._view);
_view.Caption = "Rate Quote Email";
_view.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
_view.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "XREF_ID" };
CommandField field = new CommandField();
_view.SelectedRowStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
field.ShowSelectButton = true;
field.ButtonType = ButtonType.Link;
_view.Columns.Add(field);
_view.AllowPaging = true;
_view.PageSize = 20;
_view.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Color.Cornsilk;
_view.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(_view_PageIndexChanging);
```

Code from `btnSearch_Click`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ds.Clear();
_view.DataSource = null;
ds.Load(rdr, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, "");
rdr.Close();
rdr.Dispose();
_view.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
_view.DataBind();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Clear();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ds.Load(rdr, LoadOption.PreserChanges, "");
rdr.Close();
rdr.Dispose();
_view.DataSource = null;
_view.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
_view.DataBind();
ds.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code from the `CreateChildControls` method and the `btnSearch_Click` method?  That will be the best way to see if we can find the problem

Comment: Just to make sure, is the first section `CreateChildControls` and the second section `btnSearch_Click`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. THe page indexchanging is last relevant line from createchild controls and all else below is from btnsearch_click.

Comment: Can you clarify how you know that the "orginal key values" are still in the command field?

Comment: becasue when I do a search and then click on an item in the command field, the detail & ID are displayed in the other web part and are for ID of the item in grid before search

Comment: I think your search function (as it appears) may be garbled:  the first 8 or so lines appear to be in there twice.